# Checking who added data to a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in a production server which occasionally has mysterious data occur in it. Is it possible to track the history of adding data to the table to find out why/who/when...? I am reluctant to put a trigger on the table (and it would only help for future checking) because the data volume is usually huge and this might affect performance.
I only have db-owner privilege, not sa privilege.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default value in a new column and save there the user name with SUSER_SNAME().

Example

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [id] [INT] NULL,
    [name] [NCHAR](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_1_name]  DEFAULT (SUSER_SNAME()) FOR [name]
GO
```

Comment: Is it possible to look into the history of the table to view who (and/or by which stored procedure...) added data, and when does that happen?

Comment: no such thing exists for any practical sense. you could be running traces or use some highly advance forensics in a database log file, but all that is esoteric voodoo and whispers of the arcane arts ;)